# Change ImageView onClick in an ImageAdapter

Tags: java, android, uiimageview, onclick

As the title already mentions do I want to change my ImageView onClick. I made a GridView with 4 items in an ImageAdapter. At the moment when I click on each ImageView it creates a big orange field around it. I have a custom 'pressed ImageView' and want to use that. How should I do that?

Thanks in advance

ImageAdapter:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private final String[] buttonValues;

public ImageAdapter(Context context, String[] buttonValues) {
    this.context = context;
    this.buttonValues = buttonValues;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View gridView;

    if (convertView == null) {

        gridView = new View(context);

        // get layout from mobile.xml
        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mobile, null);


        // set image based on selected text
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView
                .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

        String button = buttonValues[position];



        if (button.equals("homework")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_schedule);
        } else if (button.equals("schedule")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.schedulebut);
        } else if (button.equals("planner")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.plannerbut);
        } else {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.settingsbut);
        }

    } else {
        gridView = (View) convertView;
    }

    return gridView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return buttonValues.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

}
```

My GridView method (Activity):

```
static final String[] MOBILE_OS = new String[] { "homework", "schedule",
        "planner", "settings" };
private void setGridView() {
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, MOBILE_OS));

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                v.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.button_schedule);
                break;
            case 1:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "schedule", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case 2:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "planner",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case 3:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "settings",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }

        }
    });

}
```

My button selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/homeworkpres" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/homeworkpres" android:state_enabled="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/homework"/>
```

mobile.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center"
android:padding="5dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
    android:src="@drawable/plannerbut"
    >
</ImageView>
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        arg1.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.selector);

        }});
```

selector.xml

```
  <item 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_pressed"/>
    <item 
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_pressed"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_normal"/>
```

where btn_pressed and btn_normal are your images.

Comment: This only changes my background of the button to grey... Ill edit my post and add my ImageAdapter and Activity

Comment: I changed arg1 to homework, but it now crashes after the onClick and it still shows the orange box around it.

Comment: http://puu.sh/1U3W1 here my crashlog, fixed the orangebox by adding a listselector to the gridview (in xml)

Comment: yea that was direct way to do that, I thought that was not working for you.

Comment: But it's still crashing :S

Comment: from logs I can not check the line number, can you tell which line was having the null pointer?